# Изменить/Задать имя процессу Java

Tags: java, процесс

Если такое возможно без сторонних программ типа Launch4J.

Как изменить или задать имя процессу в коде Java при запуске приложения Java FX?

Comment: Что Вы называете процессом в данном случае? Или иначе - где должно имя поменяться ?

Comment: @Tr1nks под процессом я подразумеваю свою запущенную программу. Вообще у процесса, что бы винда отображала не `javav.exe`, а имя.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если необходимо изменить имя окна отображаемое для пользователя то

```
stage.setTitle("Hello World");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Имя процесса в диспетчере не меняется
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут [(Ссылка)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21111481/javafx-application-name) пишут что для изменения имени приложения необходимо добавить атрибут в манифест

Comment: Ссылка помогла.